# Scene phase View updating

Tags: swift, mvvm, swiftui

In app I check scene phases by scenePhase variable

```
@main
    struct StorageApp: App {
        @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
        var userManager: UserManagerProtocol = DIContainer.shared.userManager
        
        var body: some Scene {
            WindowGroup {
                ViewsFactory.build(.content)
            }
            .onChange(of: scenePhase) { newScenePhase in
                switch newScenePhase {
                case .background:
                    userManager.appEnterBackground()
                default:
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

when my view is loaded I call fetch method to get data from API

```
struct AuthorizationView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel: AuthorizationViewModel
    @State private var selection: Int?
    private let createAccount: Int
    private let importAccount: Int
    private let signIn: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(spacing: MagicNumber.x) {
                if viewModel.isLoading {
                    Spacer()
                    ProgressView()
                        .frame(idealWidth: .infinity, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                    Spacer()
                } else if viewModel.wallets.isEmpty {
                    Spacer()
                    VStack(spacing: MagicNumber.x3) {
                        IconView(name: .addressPlaceholder)
                        Text(Localizable.emptyAccounts.localized)
                            .font(.appFont(size: 18))
                            .foregroundColor(.grayText)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                } else {
                    ScrollView {
                        ForEach(viewModel.wallets.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                            if index < viewModel.wallets.count, let wallet = viewModel.wallets[index] {
                                Button {
                                    viewModel.select(wallet, in: index + 1)
                                    self.selection = signIn
                                } label: {
                                    WalletCell(of: wallet, in: index + 1)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                Button(Localizable.createAccount.localized) {
                    self.selection = createAccount
                }
                .buttonStyle(PrimaryButton())
                Button(Localizable.importAccount.localized) {
                    self.selection = importAccount
                }
                .buttonStyle(TextButton())
                .padding(.bottom, MagicNumber.x2)
                NavigationLink(destination: ViewsFactory.build(.createAccount), tag: createAccount, selection: $selection) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: ViewsFactory.build(.importAccount), tag: importAccount, selection: $selection) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: ViewsFactory.build(.signIn(viewModel.selectedWallet, deleteAction: {
                    viewModel.deleteWallet() })), tag: signIn, selection: $selection) {
                        EmptyView()
                    }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, MagicNumber.x2 + MagicNumber.x05)
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.fetchWalletsItems()
        }
    }
}
```

My viewModel

```
import Combine
import Foundation

final class AuthorizationViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var errorDescription: String
    @Published var isErrorAppears: Bool
    @Published var isLoading: Bool
    @Published var repository: StorageRepositoryProtocol
    @Published var wallets: [Wallet]
    var selectedWallet: Wallet
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    
    init(repository: StorageRepositoryProtocol) {
        errorDescription = ""
        isErrorAppears = false
        isLoading = false
        wallets = []
        selectedWallet = Wallet(address: "", name: "\(0)")
        self.repository = repository
    }
    
    func fetchWalletsItems() {
        if isLoading { return }
        isLoading = true
        cancellable = repository.getAccountsList()
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [weak self] completion in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                self.isLoading = false
                switch completion {
                case .failure(let error):
                    self.isErrorAppears = true
                    self.errorDescription = error.errorDescription
                default:
                    break
                }
            } receiveValue: { accounts in
                self.isLoading = false
                self.wallets = accounts.map({ Wallet(address: $0, name: String.randomString(length: 1))})
            }
    }
    
    func select(_ wallet: Wallet, in index: Int) {
        selectedWallet = wallet
        selectedWallet.name = "\(Localizable.address.localized) \(index)"
    }
    
    func deleteWallet() {
        wallets = wallets.filter { $0.address != selectedWallet.address }
    }
}
```

but if I use scenePhase my viewModel is being recreated and no longer sends the request because the onAppear method is called once

I can call the fetch method in the viewModel initializer, but then there will be two identical requests.

How I can send once request when my view will no longer be updated?

Answer (score 0):

I see a few mistakes that might be contributing. View model objects or MVVM is not compatible with SwiftUI but what you have looks like a model so that’s fine. Your Wallet struct needs to be `Identifiable` to use it in ForEach you can’t use indices or :.\self it is not a for loop it’s a `View` that requires `Identifiable` data to work correctly. In Combine’s `ObserableObject` we assign the pipeline to an `@Published` we don’t use sink or cancellable.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! This will not affect the behavior as the view is being recreated with a new ViewModel

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try with `@StateObject`. It should persist if the view is restored.